# Plotly line plot x-axis increment by 5

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I have a list of times I want to use with plotly to make a line graph. The Y values work perfectly, but the x's are just spaced out by 1. I would like to make them be spaced out by 5 instead, but I don't know how to do that. I saw [here](https://plot.ly/python/axes/) that you can use a range, but that range seems to be whole numbers and an interval of 1, so how do I get the x to increase by 5 for every Y value? I can't put a for loop here to do that, so I'm not sure how this would work. Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on what you want to achieve, but if you only want a specific spacing between x axis labels you can use `tick0` and `dtick` for that purpose:

```
xaxis=dict(
    tick0=0,
    dtick=5,
    ...
),
```

it would help if you show what you have and what you want for example.

Comment: I just want it to be inside of go.Scatter, and have the x value go up by 5 for each corresponding value, like y1 = 5, y2 = 10, y3 = 15, and so on

Comment: do you mean like setting `x=list(range(5, len(y)*5, 5))` in the `Scatter`? I don't think I'm getting it, maybe edit your question with the code you have and a drawing or something.

Comment: I am plotting more than one lines on the same graph so it can be compared. I have one line where each element on the x axis appears 1 unit away from the last. So the X-values look like 1,2,3,4.... But I also need to plot a line with a different set of X-values that increment by 5, so 5,10,15,20.... Right now I just have this hardcoded in, but I know thats a bad way to do it and I want to know how to fix that